# Cloudflare settings when registrar requires IP addresses

Tags: dns, ip, cloudflare

I signed up to Cloudflare, and got nameservers assigned, but within my registrar's DNS settings, I need to enter an IP address along with each NS. I tried using random addresses from [this page](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/), but my registrar won't take subnet masks (`/<number>` after the IP). The site this is for is hosted with WP Engine.

What IP addresses should I use along with each Cloudflare NS on my registrar's DNS settings. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

When moving to Cloudflare you can't merely set an NS DNS record, you actually need to move your Authoritative Name Server to Cloudflare.

An NS record is used to delegate a subdomain to a set of name servers, but in order to use Cloudflare you need to actually delegate the Name Servers of your domain to Cloudflare.

There are tutorials on how you can do this on the Cloudflare Help Centre: [How do I change my domain nameservers?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206455647)

Comment: This is what I think I did in my registrar's DNS settings page for the domain I'm taking about here (or I'm missing something), but the settings page require to enter an IP address with each NS.

Comment: FWIW, I did exactly as described above, not “merely set[ting] an NS DNS record” it seems, but changing DNS settings from my registrar's DNS _settings_ page (as I had done many times). Looking up IP addresses from the NS assigned by Cloudflare _did_ work.

Answer (score -1):

One workaround I've found was to use https://www.whatsmydns.net or ping the NS, then I entered the IP addresses I had found.

Comment: FWIW, it does work. So whoever needs to enter an IP address along with a Cloudflare nameserver on their registrar's DNS settings page can lookup the IP's by pinging each domain assigned by Cloudflare as NS.